# Oracle Reports Pie Chart not Showing in PDF on windows server 2012

Tags: oracle, windows-server-2012, oraclereports

Pie chart not showing in PDF when running oracle report on windows server 2012.Instead showing a rectangular box . I also changed the PDF reader. I tried on version 10, 11 and acrobat reader DC. Message showing there was error processing the page.

Any help highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Which Reports Builder version is it? Do you see the chart while running the report directly in the Builder?

Comment: Report Builder 11.1.1.2.0   64 bit
yeah I see the chart perfectly while running the report from report builder and also If I extract in PDF through report builder. Problem comes when running the report through oracle forms . the report gets successfully finished but shows error message "there was error processing the page"

Comment: Thank you for the additional info; unfortunately, I wouldn't know what's wrong, but I hope that someone else will be able to assist. Meanwhile, have a look at "Graph support" section, here: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/formsandreports/use-reports/pbr_pdf002.htm#RSPUB23423 . Maybe it'll help.